# Play sound when item added to cart on iOS browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, woocommerce, web-audio-api

I have a website using WooCommerce.
I want to play a short shound every time an item added to cart.
I have a mp3 file ready.

I decided to used this https://github.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound
It's working on PC, but I can't hear the sound on iOS browser.

my script is as following

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
      var anchor = anchors[i];
      anchor.onclick = function() {
          $.playSound("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/my_sound.mp3");
      }
  }
}</script>
```

What should I do to play the sound on iOS browser?
Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to rewrite the script to use only jQuery, more solid :)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a').on('click', function(){
        jQuery.playSound("<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/my_sound.mp3");
    });
});
</script>
```

Report back if there is still an issue with iOS.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would remove it from this action:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tap_sound' );
```

and just add it hard coded (for checking purposes) on the footer.

Seconds, I would use jQuery which can be much cleaner. example:
[https://webdev-il.blogspot.com/2017/10/trigger-audio-and-playing-sounds-with.html](http://First,%20I%20would%20remove%20it%20from%20this%20action:%20add_action(%20'wp_enqueue_scripts',%20'tap_sound'%20);%20and%20just%20add%20it%20hard%20coded%20(for%20checking%20purposes)%20on%20the%20footer.%20%20Seconds,%20I%20would%20use%20jQuery%20which%20can%20be%20much%20cleaner.%20example:%20https://webdev-il.blogspot.com/2017/10/trigger-audio-and-playing-sounds-with.html)

Comment: Thank you! I decided to use that jQuery on your comment.
It's working on PC, but I can't hear the sound on iOS browser.
I pasted my script. Can anyone check and see what I should do?